# Sync 2 Folders in different GIT-Repos

Tags: git, version-control, synchronization

I have 2 GIT-Repos with a Drupal Instance in, each. The Instances have totaly different modules and so on, but they use the same theme. I would like to sync these theme dirs anyhow. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this theme into a separate repository and then add it as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) to both repos.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that answer.  I must investigate this further.  I want to balance two extremes in design while keeping them as essentially separate products.  We all know the compromise:  I have an automatic approach with less user control, a manual approach for detail people who want control and I may branch a lot while figuring out compromises, but there are at least three paths there and this may be the way to track them.  I can't dream of making them compilation or configuration options until I know what they are.